# Having compatibility issues on Google Play with some devices

Tags: android, google-play, device, compatibility

I've recently just launched my app, and it's going really well! I am having issues with some users, though. Users on older devices such as the Nexus 5X, Huawei P10 Lite, and Meizu M2 Note are saying they are unable to download the app on Google Play because it says it is incompatible with their device. I've already checked the Developer Console and it says the app should support these devices (except the Meizu that one doesn't even show up in the catalog). I've also already run emulators mimicking the devices and everything works fine. All of them are running Android 8.0 which I know for sure is supported by my app.

I've been looking all over google for a way to solve this, but honestly I have no idea what to do anymore. This is my first real app and I can't help but get the feeling that I'm missing some crucial step for widespread release.

---

Here's my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.balanstudios.einar.workouttimer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" android:required="false"></uses-feature> 


    <application
        android:name=".BaseApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_work_icon_small"
        android:label="Robota"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_work_icon_small_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/WorkoutTimerLight">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/WorkoutTimerLight"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/WorkoutTimerLight"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.balanstudios.einar.workouttimer"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

---

Does anyone have any ideas? I would really appreciate any help!

[Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.balanstudios.einar.workouttimer)

Answer (score 0):

Your app has `min Sdk = 23` (this gradle line)

```
 minSdkVersion 23
```

The complaints are probably from users on older versions of Android.